# elements from first row in a matrix operated with one element taken from each row, iterating with all the elements of rows

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, combinations

Consider a 2D list in python. Taking the first list of given 2D list, I want to do XOR operation of each element from the first list with one element each from subsequent lists so that I have n-1 elements operated with that one element.

Example - 
list = [[0,1], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2]]

combinations formed will be - 
0^0^0,
0^0^1,
0^0^2,
0^1^0,
0^1^1,
0^1^2,
0^2^0,
0^2^1,
0^2^2,
0^3^0,
0^3^1,
0^3^2,
1^0^0,
1^0^1,
1^0^2,
1^1^0,
1^1^1,
1^1^2,
1^2^0,
1^2^1,
1^2^2,
1^3^0,
1^3^1,
1^3^2

condition - The size of any of the list or sublists is not predefined

Answer (score 1):

```py
for_the_product = [[0,1], [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2]]
for one_tuple in itertools.product(*for_the_product):
    do_something_with(one_tuple)
```

[More explanation in the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). The `*` gives each elements of your initial list (`for_the_product` in my code) as an argument to the `product` function.